# Aggregate the mean score of team members score

Tags: r, aggregate, mean

I have data of team members. Each team is about 5 members. The typical aggregate function will allow me to compute the average score of the whole team. However, I am interested, for each participant, to compute the average score of the participant's team members excluding the participant's score. Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question properly, you can try this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(team = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5), rep("C", 5)),
             player = letters[1:15],
             score = 1:15)

# find aggregate team scores and number of team members
team_means <- df %>%
  group_by(team) %>%
  summarise(team_sum = sum(score, na.rm = TRUE),
            team_n = n())

# find average of rest of team's performance
# this is the the "remaining players' average"; the "- 1" could be removed for the team average.
left_join(df, team_means, by = "team") %>%
  mutate(average = (team_sum - score) / (team_n - 1)) %>%
  select(team, player, score, average)

# A tibble: 15 x 4
   team  player score average
   <chr> <chr>  <int>   <dbl>
 1 A     a          1    3.5 
 2 A     b          2    3.25
 3 A     c          3    3   
 4 A     d          4    2.75
 5 A     e          5    2.5 
 6 B     f          6    8.5 
 7 B     g          7    8.25
 8 B     h          8    8   
 9 B     i          9    7.75
10 B     j         10    7.5 
11 C     k         11   13.5 
12 C     l         12   13.2 
13 C     m         13   13   
14 C     n         14   12.8 
15 C     o         15   12.5
```

Comment: Please avoid answering questions with no clear problem statement, sample data and/or sample code.

Comment: Fair enough, noted.